# How do I configure Spring load balancing strategy to use the instance that is currently having least traffic?

Tags: java, spring, load-balancing, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

I'm using spring cloud load balancer as a client side load balancer in a spring microservice project. I know by default Spring load balancer uses round robin strategy. But   for my use case `Least connections` strategy is best suited. Where the instance handling least number of connections get the request routed to it. After digging through docs I have found `@LoadBalancerClient` annotation lets you canfigure the routing algorithm.
So, I did this:

```
@Configuration
@LoadBalancerClient(configuration = BalancerConfig.class)
public class RestConfig {
    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    RestTemplate restClient(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

For the class BalancerConfig.java I have:

```
@Configuration
public class BalancerConfig {
    @Bean
    ReactorLoadBalancer<ServiceInstance> randomLoadBalancer(Environment environment,
            LoadBalancerClientFactory loadBalancerClientFactory) {
        String name = environment.getProperty(LoadBalancerClientFactory.PROPERTY_NAME);
         // currently selects an instance randomly of a given service.
        // but I want to switch it to use the instance that is currently having least 
       // traffic
        return new RandomLoadBalancer(loadBalancerClientFactory
                .getLazyProvider(name, ServiceInstanceListSupplier.class),
                name);
    }
}
```

Please tell me is it even possible with Spring application gateway?

Comment: It's possible, but we've not written one. It will need to be custom

Comment: @spencergibb thanks for letting  me know. I need to look for some alternative solution in that case. Can you provide some solution on what to use in case I want to use least connections strategy

Answer (score 1):

If you want all clients to use a custom policy, you just only need to define a ReactorLoadBalancer bean as below

```
@Bean
ReactorLoadBalancer<ServiceInstance> randomLoadBalancer(Environment environment,
                                                        LoadBalancerClientFactory loadBalancerClientFactory) {
    String name = environment.getProperty(LoadBalancerClientFactory.PROPERTY_NAME);
    return new RandomLoadBalancer(loadBalancerClientFactory
            .getLazyProvider(name, ServiceInstanceListSupplier.class),
            name);
}
```

But if you want to customize a different policy for each client,you need to do like this

```
public class RestConfig {
    @Bean
    ReactorLoadBalancer<ServiceInstance> randomLoadBalancer(Environment environment,
                                                            LoadBalancerClientFactory loadBalancerClientFactory) {
        String name = environment.getProperty(LoadBalancerClientFactory.PROPERTY_NAME);
        return new RandomLoadBalancer(loadBalancerClientFactory
                .getLazyProvider(name, ServiceInstanceListSupplier.class),
                name);
    }
}
```

Configure two routes

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=web
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://web
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/web/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=reactive-web
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://reactive-web
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/reactive/**
```

Run GateWayApplication

```
@LoadBalancerClient(value = "reactive-web",configuration = RestConfig .class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class GateWayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GateWayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

In this way, the first route uses RoundRobinLoadBalancer, and the second route uses RandomLoadBalancer.

Comment: No I do not wa that. I want all my clients to use least connections policy

Comment: I wanted all route to use least connections policy but as I came to know from @spencergibb they have not written a built in one. So, may be I need to switch to something else here